# Why do I get '?' in the url 'http://localhost/BackBoneWorkspace/helloDemoMVC/?#login' in backbone js app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using backbone.js.

I have a login form and I handle it's submit behaviour in events of login view.

What I have done is when user enters email and password, I have shown it on details view, but my problem is I get `?` character in URL when I click on login button...

So does any one knows about this, please help.

Here is my event handling code in login.js

```
events:{

    'submit form' : 'detailsPage'
},

 detailsPage: function(){

    console.log("submit event fired");

     myApp.usermodel.set({"userName":$("#email").val(),"password":$("#password").val()});

    myApp.collection.add(myApp.usermodel);
    myApp.usermodel.save();
    myApp.details= new myApp.DetailsView();
    myApp.details.render(myApp.usermodel.get("userName"), myApp.usermodel.get("password"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `detailsPage` function, you need to prevent the form from actually submitting, by called the `event.preventDefault()` function. That `event` object will be passed to `detailsPage` as a first parameter.

```
detailsPage: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
}
```